# want to use polyfill with HTML5 to make date type work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polyfills

I want to use polyfill with HTML5 to make date type work in firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,
   maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
<title>better-dateinput-polyfill demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/
                        modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" />   
</body>
</html>
```

I used this answer 
[How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

and this is demo and it works fine
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/BMEc9/

but this error appears to me (
TypeError: a.support is undefined  polyfiller.js (line 1, col 1413
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer version of jQuery; `support()` was not added until 1.3: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/