# im trying to select current date in date box it work in chrome but not work in firefox help me

Tags: php, firefox, datebox

im trying to select current date in date box it work in chrome but not work in firefox help me

```
<html>
    Select Date <input type="date" name="det"  >
</html>
```

Comment: Thats because firefox don't support that yet! See CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=date

Answer (score 0):

This input is not **yet** supported by firefox. It display a normal text-box.

Look here for workaround :)   [How to get HTML 5 input type=“date” working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because firefox don't support that yet!
See CanIUse:

http://www.caniuse.com/#search=date

Alternativ you can use a JQuery DatePicker See:

(You can test it right on the website an see that it works in the firefox)

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/