# firefox input type date issue

Tags: php, date, firefox

I have html form where I am using input type date for a text box but calender is not appearing in browser. I am using firefox 35.0. I searched on google but did not find any answer related to my condition so what will be the solution???
**How Do I implement input type date in firefox??**

Comment: Is it working on chrome??

Comment: yes its working on chrome

Comment: I think you should implement jquery ui datepicker..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Comment: look at [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=date) , so it is not working in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find from their documentation that it is unimplemented. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility

I would recommend you go through MDN always for questions specific to Firefox. They have documented things really well.