# Webshims and Input Type="Date" not work well

Tags: javascript, html, webshim

it's the first time i ask your help.
I'm trying to use Webshim for loading on any browser a input type=date. 
I use this topic: [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)
and everythings works well.
But when i try to use internal references to the javascript library something goes wrong.
The Code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
      webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');

      webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
      webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
    webshim.setOptions("forms-ext", {
        "date": {
            "calculateWidth": false} });
    });    
    </script>
```

If i use a internal library, i get this warning and nothing appears when i click on the date icon:
**"could not get clear text from form cfg"**.