# A calender won't display with firefox

Tags: symfony, date, firefox, calendar, twig

I want to display a calender using the code below ,it works fine with google chrome but with Firefox it appear like text field .

How can I resolve this problem I want to display a calender and it does not matter which browser is used.

my buildform:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('startDate', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            // this is actually the default format for single_text
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        ->add('EndDate', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            // this is actually the default format for single_text
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
}
```

my twig:

```
<div>
 {{ form_widget(form.startDate}}
 {{ form_widget(form.EndDate}}   
</div>
```

Comment: any errors in the console ?

Comment: no ,no errors in the console !!

Comment: any resources not beeing loaded ?   the css not 404-ing ?    does the developer tools say that css is applied to the calendar parts which are not displayed properly? can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony Form Builder calendar does not show on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329899/symfony-form-builder-calendar-does-not-show-on-firefox). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10/22987203#22987203) as well

Comment: What's the reason for not using: `'widget' => 'choice'`? That is the default choice and renders 3 select inputs.