# <input type="date"> is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  Birthday: <input type="date" id="datepicker">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to pick date from the calender. I have used Date input from HTML5
    this code is working fine in IE and Chrome
    and not working in Mozilla 
    please help me to fix the code

Comment: there is nothing to fix...http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/Vq65z/504/

Comment: You are right. Mozilla does not yet support any of the calendar based input types. There is a tracking bug of you're interested in following progress

Comment: yeah, it's laughable that moz bragged about the HTML5 stuff, what, 7 years ago, and they still have not gotten around to implementing those basic UI necessities; no wonder they are slipping...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 2):

The HTML  element is a specific version of the  element used to create an input field accepting a date.

Browsers generate a control for entering, and changing, the date. This date includes a year, month and day. The control itself varies from one browser to another; `browsers not supporting` this type will display a simple text control.

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

```
use datetime picker jquery plugin  will be a good option
```

[Read this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

or try this code :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```