# How to give a date format as dd-mm-yyyy in IE as like I am getting in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, date, internet-explorer, browser

As input `type=date` won't works in IE is there any possible way to get `dd-mm-yyyy` format same like as we are getting in other browsers? Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Comment: Use DateJs for force format https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

Comment: did u try below added answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested below code in IE/Chrome/Firefox and its working fine.

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
  webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
  webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
<input type="date" />
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I tested in IE(version 11) but still its not working.