# I want to block chrome extensions or any extensions when someone use my application(Codeignite baser)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, logic

I want to block chrome extensions or any extensions when someone use my application(Codeignite base) being used by other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of input tag which uses type="date". This does not work in firefox.

The better solution here is to use datepicker which will work in all the browser.

But if you still want to use the same code then you need to refer link:
[How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)