# Date tag in html not display as date in internet explorer

Tags: html

I have date tag in html which is working well while opened in chrome but is not displayed as date in internet explorer. 
How can I get a date field date in all types of browsers?

Comment: Right now, this question isn't clear because we don't know what you wrote. Please provide your code and the output that you are receiving in each browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show CODE!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10) - but read the comments and follow the links

Comment: I would suggest adding more content to this question, to help us get to the answer that you need to resolve this problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=date) built-in date input is not supported in IE.
You can add some kind of JS datepicker and bind it to the datq type of input. One of the good examples of ddatepicker can be found [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).