# Date picker is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

```
<div class="bootstrap-datepicker">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputname"> Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control pull-right datepicker" id="datepicker" value="">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>  
        </div>
</div>  
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="time">Time</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control timepicker" value="">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The script I added is:

```
 $(function () {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format:'dd-mm-yyyy'
  });
  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
    showInputs: false
  });
});
```

included script file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it does not working in Internet Explorer. Please help me with this.

Comment: Which version? I hope it's not 5 or 6

Comment: Generally, elements inside label get us in a situation like this.

Comment: Please specify what version of Internet Explorer you are referring to.

Comment: internet explorer 8,9 and 10.

Comment: Is there any solution u get?? Because these below suggestions are not working with IE. I am using IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
 $('#inputboxid').datepicker({
       showOn: "button",
       onSelect: function()
       {
         // this will execute
         $(this).change();
       }
    });
```

Comment: Does not work in IE11. In Chrome it adds additional button.

Comment: Try this answer on SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :-

```html
$("input.pickerClass").datepicker();
```