# Silverstripe 3 show date picker on template

Tags: templates, datepicker, silverstripe

Is there a certain way to get the datepicker to show on the template?
I have used the following code:

```
TextField::create('DateFrom','Date From')             
                ->setAttribute('data-datepicker', true)
                ->setAttribute('data-date-format', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
```

I added this to my config yaml file:

```
DateField:
  default_config:
    showcalendar: true
```

The text box shows but no date picker shows when the textbox is clicked on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. Either you use the SilverStripe `DateField` like so:

```
DateField::create('DateFrom','Date From')->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
```

The SilverStripe DateField will render a date-picker using JavaScript.

Or you use an HTML5 date field that relies on the browser implementation for the date-picker. For that to work, you need to also set the `type` of the field to `date` (it defaults to `text`):

```
DateField::create('DateFrom','Date From')
    ->setAttribute('type', 'date')
    ->setConfig('datavalueformat', 'dd-MM-yyyy') // Server side validation
    ->setAttribute('data-datepicker', true)
    ->setAttribute('data-date-format', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try using the SS datefield which didn't work. The HTML5 datefield works, thank you. One thing, the placeholder text is showing as dd- ---- yyyy for some reason. I can't get month to show.

Comment: @Craig silverstripe isn't adding any placeholders by default… so I guess the issue is browser-related, or a problem with some JS library you're using? Your `data-` attributes make me think there's some additional JS code involved.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a DateField instead of a TextField.

```
TextField::create('DateFrom','Date From')             
            ->setAttribute('data-datepicker', true)
            ->setAttribute('data-date-format', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
```

should be

```
DateField::create('DateFrom','Date From')             
            ->setAttribute('data-datepicker', true)
            ->setAttribute('data-date-format', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
```

Comment: I don’t think the HTML5-way is a bad choice. I personally dislike the pickerfield you get with SS-DateField. You still can use a DateField but than you have to disable the JS-Picker from SS and use a polyfill. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10

Comment: The `DateField` doesn't use the HTML5 attributes to enable the date-picker, it's `->setConfig('showcalendar', true)`. If you want an HTML5 date-picker, a `TextField` should work as well…