# Datepicker not working inside the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a form inside a modal.

I am trying to update one input field  in to a datepicker, but the calendar is not showing up.

Here is my html head:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.useragentman.com/tests/html5Forms/shared/js/modernizr.com/Modernizr-2.5.3.forms.js"></script>
```

```
<script>$('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker(); </script>

<style>
body {   margin: 0;
font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif; }
.datepicker {
  z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
}
</style>
```

My html body:-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" name="passdata" action="save.php" method="POST">              

<div class="col-xs-6"><label>Joining Date</label>
 <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  <br/> </div>
</div>  

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:80%; margin-bottom:15px;">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myModal3").modal({backdrop: "static"});
$("#myModal3").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

This is how I am getting the html output:-

[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JKYV.png)

Also nothing is happening when I click on the input box.

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input type is `text`, replaced it to `date` and it will work well

```
<input type="date" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
```

Here is [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/fesizokiko/edit?html,output)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is not working. Not eve on your JS bin. Its showing the same like the my output. :(

Comment: mmm.. added a screenshot from my jsbin. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing it on firefox. After your comment tried on internet explorer and chrome. and it worked on chrome but not on firefox and chrome . how do i get it working on all the browsers ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22983013/5099208 this might answer your question regarding Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Modal box is correct html structure. I made an example with your codes with correct html structure. Please check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.useragentman.com/tests/html5Forms/shared/js/modernizr.com/Modernizr-2.5.3.forms.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<form>
                   <div class="col-xs-6"><label>Joining Date</label>
                     <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                     <br/> 
                  </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


      <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker();
$("#myModal3").modal({backdrop: "static"});
$("#myModal3").modal('show');
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above comments they don't answer the real problem. Datepicker.js or css plugin does no work on modal. In a normal form e.g.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-end-date="0d" required="">                                            
</div>
```

That code works in a general form. When you transfer the same code to a modal, it does not work. (That's if your modal contains a form field which takes date input)
Using ''type="date"' in input field just triggers the default browser calendar pop but not the datepicker plugin calendar pop.(Firefox & Edge Browsers).
In-short the datepicker plugin does not support calendar pop ups on modals hence just use the default date type:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" required="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-datepicker 
{
    z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
}
```

Comment: It's recommended (and a good practice) to annotate your answer and not just put the code/script/tag in the answer. Help OP understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the datepicker was displaying below the viewport.
If the input with the datepicker calendar is in a modal, the top position of the jquery ui element `<div id="ui-datepicker-div"></div>`(this is added to the `<body/>`) will be incorrectly calculated.

Chrome (*top="285px"*):
[image: top position of ui datepicker element in Chrome]

IE11 (*top="2853.13px"*):
[image: top position of ui datepicker element in IE11]

As you can see the top position is significantly higher in IE11, which is because it's including the window scroll position.

To get round this you can do the following:

1. Check for IE11 browser only - **NB! This is generally not recommended**
2. Find the to position of the input where the calendar should appear below(elementTopPosition)
3. Deduct the "elementTopPosition" from the window scroll position and add the height of the "elementTopPosition"
4. Set the new top position to `datePickerIEPosition`

```
// IE11 fix
var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
if(isIE11) {
   $('.modal-body input.date-field').on('click', function() {
      var datePickerIEPosition = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).outerHeight();
      var $datepickerDiv = $('#ui-datepicker-div');
      if($(this).is(":focus")) {
         $datepickerDiv.css({ top: datePickerIEPosition + 'px' });
      } 
   });
}
```