# Getting datepicker to work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

The `<input type="date"/>` is not supported in Firefox. I read that to be able to use date type in all browser you can check using modernizer and if not supported you can fall back to use javascript to show the datepickerr.

I went to https://modernizr.com, clicked Development Build, and downloaded the file containing all the JS code. I then added this file (modernizr-custom.js) to my web project. At the top of the relevant page I'm working on, I added:

```
<script src="modernizr-custom.js">

<!-- Used for calendar picker -->
<script>
    $(function(){
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                }
             );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Below in the file I have my html line of code:

```
<input type="date" name = "date" placeholder = "Date" required>
```

However, after all that, I still cannot get the datepicker to show in Firefox. I am new to JavaScript, so I am hoping someone can point out what I did wrong.

(This is not a duplicate question. The link below does not describe how to use Modernizr with the function I provided to solve this issue, which is what I am asking. [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10))

Comment: `type="date"` works in Firefox as of version 57.

Comment: It does. OSX is still in beta but works on this page: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/html5-input-types/

Comment: Please ask a NEW question with the title "How to use Modernizr to implement HTML5 date handling in Firefox < 57"