# Date picker not working in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular-formly

I am new to angular , date picker is not working in IE and fine in other browser :
code is :

```
 <div  *ngIf="question.type!='date'">

       <input type ="date"  class="form-control" [formControlName]="question.key"
                     [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">
```

question.type data is coming from backend .
any suggestion whats wrong here?

Comment: input type="date" is an HTML5 feature which may or may not be supported by certain browsers. You need to use modernizr to check if a browser supports a feature. If not you can use polyfills to replace it with a similar behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of IE that you are using? if You are using HTML5 syntax then it may not be supported by all browsers.

Check the following thread.

[How to get HTML 5 input type="date" working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

If you don't want the above solution, then please change the input filed attribute `type="date"`.  to `type="text"`. And let me know if you have any clarification.

Comment: did your changed the type for this attribute?  `[type]="question.type"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this particular polyfill for your angular application. This will allow input type date to work on IE as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-input-polyfill

Comment: did you try it yourself?