# EditorFor type=date, show only mask

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, html-helper

I have a model class:

```
public class mOrderSnapshot
{
[Display(Name = "Birthday")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

I try to insert a date in input.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "usercontrol"})
```

But I see only the mask  **дд.мм.гггг**
Why I can't insert a value(date).

Comment: try check in other browser. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "usercontrol", @type="date"})
```

**OR:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new {@class = "usercontrol", @type="date"})
```

Comment: it doesnt work and I have to use , @type = "date"

Comment: I had some problems. @type="date" doestn't work in FireFox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10

Comment: @godot if it's for me , i know it and wrote it under question.

Comment: Firefox 57+ supports input type=date

Answer (score 0):

I must use this one:
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

**DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}**