# Material-UI TextField type date not working with IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Inside my react project, I'm using TextField from material_ui and it works perfectly in chrome and mozilla, but it doesn't work in IE ....
This is a piece of my code just to show how I use Material-UI

```
import {TextField} from "@material-ui/core";
import Moment from "moment";

<TextField 
   onChange={this.handleChange} 
   id="date" 
   label="Date" 
   type="date" 
   defaultValue={Moment(this.state.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} 
/>
```

I know there are problems with IE ... instead to use textField what's possible way to use and have the same aspect of Material component?

there are other material components to use a calendar that work with IE?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `<Input>` from material-ui? I cannot test on IE but it's worth trying, `Input` instead of `TextField`

Comment: not work  look this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10 - Here is an example of how to get `date` working in ie10 with an library called `Webshim` you may try this approach

Comment: not useful for my case ...is to old library, last commit 2016, and i need something work with react not jQuery ...but thanks