# Is there an alternative to Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, shared-hosting

I have been asked by my running club to migrate their membership spreadsheet to a web-based application.  I've created an ASP.NET 3.5 solution with SQL Server and it works fine on my development machine.  However, I have included an Ajax Calendar Extender (not unreasonably I think) and it turns out that the shared hosting server will not support this technology (which seems to require a trust level = full).  Rather than look for a new shared hosting provider, can anyone point me to a quick and easy way to implement a similar functionality to the Calendar extender without falling foul of the shared hosting supplier's rules?  I should add that I'm doing this pro bono so I'd rather spend as little time as possible :)

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) like so

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use Ajax Toolkit.

Depending on your needs, you might use pure JavaScript, or any specific library.

If you need replacement for Calendar Extender, you can use [datepicker from jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
   <script>
     $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
   </script>

   <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

There are many references to JS datepickers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528706/is-there-any-lightweight-javascript-date-picker) too

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar situation a few months ago and, given the unfortunate buggy-ness of recent builds of Ajax Control Toolkit, I finally decided to invest in licensing Developer Express' libraries. Much more stable IMHO.