# Disable manual entry of date in datePicker

Tags: datepicker

I would like to make the user to select date from datepicker but not allow him to enter manually.I would like to use html5 date picker,css and javascript but not jquery.It should work fine in both chrome and InternetExplorer(IE) browser.Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080397/6251232

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any lightweight JavaScript date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528706/is-there-any-lightweight-javascript-date-picker)